# Why there is a grounding on device with two prong cord?

Tags: grounding

I am curious why there is the grounding on a device with two prong cord? As far as I know there should be 3 prong cord to make the grounding working.[image]

Comment: The third prong is a female one, is it not?

Comment: And what about the tabs on the side?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is the equivalent of a typo: OP asks about a two-prong connector having only two contacts, when in fact there's way more contacts visible. Thus, there's really no question to be answered.

Comment: My house power outlet mains have only tho holes. the cord fits perfectly, but is it safe to use? So, my questions is regarding my safety. Why you think there is no question to answer?

Comment: @Laurvnas: "*So, my questions is regarding my safety.*" There is no mention of safety in your question. You can edit it to improve the question.

Comment: @Laurynas Valuzis Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schuko) article.

Comment: Unless your house has an old style socket, schuko sockets have two ground tabs - little metal wipers top and bottom that contact the earth connections on the cable.

Comment: If your sockets don't have the wipers, then the issue is with the sockets not being earthed, **not** the cable which is earthed.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your house has an old style unearthed socket (CEE 7-1), the more modern [schuko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schuko) sockets (CEE 7-3) have two earth tabs - little metal wipers top and bottom that contact the earth connections on the cable. These are found in the majority of EU countries (notable exceptions include the UK and France).

There is also a second style of socket (CEE 7-5) that has a earth pin that engages with the hole in the plug. These are typically found in France.

If your sockets don't have the wipers, or the earth pin, then the issue is with the sockets not being earthed, not the cable which is wired with a hybrid (CEE 7-7) earthed plug compatible with both styles of socket.

Answer (score 1):

That is a grounded plug. It just fits into two different types of grounded sockets. It will also fit into ungrounded sockets, but in general devices with grounded plugs shall (or at least should) be connected to grounded sockets for safety and correct operation of equipment.